# Using geoms inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to write a function to plot shot location data. My function sets an image of  an NHL rink as the background and then calls `geom_point` and `coord_flip` to map the location data correctly.

```
geom_shotplot <- function(...){
  annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(png::readPNG("man/figures/full-rink.png"), 
                               width = unit(1,"npc"), 
                               height = unit(1,"npc"))) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_flip()
}
```

However, the function returns an error:

```
x_coords <- rnorm(100)
y_coords <- rnorm(100)

my_data <- data.frame(x_coords=rnorm(100, sd=10),y_coords=rnorm(100, sd=10))

ggplot(my_data, aes(x=x_coords, y=y_coords)) +
   geom_shotplot()
```

Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?

When I use the same code outside my function, it works perfectly:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=x_coords, y=y_coords)) +
annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(png::readPNG("man/figures/full-rink.png"), 
                               width = unit(1,"npc"), 
                               height = unit(1,"npc"))) +
    geom_point() +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

What is causing this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Try with `function(...) { list(annotation_custom(rest_of_code), geom_point(), coord_flip()) }`

Comment: @Phil This worked for me, thanks! If you write this as an answer (and maybe say why it worked?) i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The go-to first step in troubleshooting custom functions for `ggplot2` for me is to first try to set the layers into a list. So in case where your custom function doesn't work here, you can turn to:

```
geom_shotplot <- function() {
      list(
   annotation_custom(grid::rasterGrob(png::readPNG("man/figures/full-rink.png"), 
                               width = unit(1,"npc"), 
                               height = unit(1,"npc"))),
    geom_point(),
    coord_flip()
     )
}
```

The key aspect to remember is that `ggplot2` objects are lists, with each element of the list consisting of the layers you have specified using `+`. What I can't fully explain is why in some cases building a function using `+` within will not work. But I haven't had any issues with creating a `list()` of the layers.

Note that you don't need the `...` in `function()` because you're not looking to pass any arguments when you call the function later.